# How to check if some text in a RichTextBox is selected

Tags: vb.net, winforms, richtextbox

I am creating a text editor and I want to add copy, paste and cut functions in the Edit Menu. I want these MenuItems to only to be enabled when there's an active selection.

I have a function that searches and highlights but there doesn't seem to be a trigger to check for in order to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RichTextBox.SelectionChanged event ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged)) fires when the selection of text within the control has changed.

The RichTextBox.SelectionLength property ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionlength)) will return the number of characters selected in control.

Handle the SelectionChanged event and set the Enabled property of the menu items based on if the SelectionLength is greater than 0:

```vb
Private Sub MyRichTextBox_SelectionChanged(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyRichTextBox.SelectionChanged
    MyMenuItem1.Enabled = MyRichTextBox.SelectionLength > 0
    MyMenuItem2.Enabled = MyMenuItem1.Enabled
    MyMenuItem3.Enabled = MyMenuItem1.Enabled
End Sub
```